# How to do Wordpress lable value as editable

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, label

I am Creating custom from for wordpress ,

Where I have options for some of input lables also editable..

```
$this->_env = array(
            'OneTimeOnly' => __("One Time Only", "wpjobboard"),
            'Recurring' => __("Recurring", "wpjobboard"),

        );
        $e = $this->create("wpjobboard_clickandpledge_Paymentoptions", Daq_Form_Element::TYPE_CHECKBOX);
        $e->setValue($this->conf("wpjobboard_clickandpledge_Paymentoptions"));
        $e->setLabel(__("Payment Options", "wpjobboard"));
        $e->addValidator(new Daq_Validate_InArray(array_keys($this->_env)));
        foreach($this->_env as $k => $v) {
            $e->addOption($k, $k,  $v);
        }
        $this->addElement($e, "clickandpledge");
```

This is one of the field value from my form

Where  `$e->setLabel(__("Payment Options", "wpjobboard"));`

user can able to change the **Payment Options** lable value

any suggessions

Answer (score 0):

Create a theme options using the following link http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-theme-options/. Or create it using any plugin like Option tree (https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/). It will create an option in the admin area(theme options). In that page admin can update the field label.

Comment: I am Creating custom plugin so I have created a form field like above with out plugins is there any options to edit without using third party plugins